# How to enter value to android NumberPicker with calabash

Tags: calabash, numberpicker, calabash-android

I'm trying to make it working with next code:

```
enter_text("android.widget.EditText id:'numberpicker_input'", value)
```

But it doesn't work sometimes. The problem is that if number picker lose focus it is removing `EditText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was just my lack of ruby and calabash. I clone calabash android and start investigating and found next solution:

```
  query("android.widget.NumberPicker id:'minutes_picker'", setValue:minutes)
```

`minutes` should be integer value

Answer (score 0):

In my case of choose number picker in alert dialog, I define custom step in ~/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb.

```
Given /^I set the NumberPicker value to (\d+)$/ do |value|
   query("android.widget.NumberPicker", setValue:Integer(value)-1)
end
```

(1 is the first one of picker values, not 0.)

Then in a scenario, when alert dialog whith number picker is showing,

```
Given I set the NumberPicker value to 2
```

Hope this can help you.